# Sharing Visual Studio installation options with team

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

The VS2017 installation process includes dozens of options to choose from ("Wokloads", "Individual Components", etc.). Having spent quite a lot of time making my selections, I would like to be able to save a record of my choices so that I may:

- Archive these for future reference (e.g., forced re-install)
- Share with teammates.

Is there any mechanism for doing so that doesn't involve taking 4 or 5 screenshots and meticulously comparing them side-by-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we have this feature inside the VS installer, please run the VS installer as administrator and click More, there have two options: Import configuration/Export configuration as below:
[image]

We can export the configuration then import it like the following:

[image]